# Quincykit stopped collecting crashes

Tags: ios, plcrashreporter, quincykit

I checked my crash-log managed by QuincyKit and the last one appeared on February 14th and nothing more. The iTunes report instead list 7 crashes just for yesterday, of course without giving any detail.
I tried emulating a crash on my app and I received error:

> data too short after length-prefix of 517
>   2016-02-22 17:57:47.619 inArrivoHD[6847:1109323] Could not parse crash report

At any rate, I tried it on another project and received no error, yet the crash was not submitted either. What is really strange is that I put a log at the start of crash_v200.php and it was never printed, like the url was not called by the iOS app.
Has anyone got any ida why the system might have topped working on February 14th?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was apparently due to apache. Once I restarted it, all the crashlogs started to flock in.